# Image source not being read/found (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a very simple view page, and for some reason, it is not grabbing my images.  At first I thought there was something wrong with my routes to my images and that they were off, until I put down the entire route (shown below). I still am getting the same error as I was before, however if I take that same image route and paste it into a tab on chrome, I'm able to view the image.

```
%img{:alt => "Testing Image", :type => "image/jpg", :src => 'images/testImage.jpg'
```

For some unknown reason, the console gives me a `404 (Not Found)`

My legit route that chrome won't allow me to open is, but for proof that i'm not crazy: `File:///Users/tomJohnson/Desktop/myAppProjectName/app/assets/images/testImage.jpg`

Does anybody have any idea what on earth i'm doing wrong? I'm literally going crazy with this.

Comment: Does it work by using `image_path` or any other? `%img{ alt: 'Testing Image', type: 'image/jpg', src: image_path('images/testImage.jpg') }`?

Comment: so....i do get errors if i try that, i get  `The asset "images/testImage.jpg" is not present in the asset pipeline.` but I feel like it is closer

Comment: Oh man, you are the best!!! Thank you so much!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead using a "normal" anchor tag, and having to handle the source path, you can use the [image_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-image_tag) helper:

```
= image_tag 'images/testImage', alt: 'Testing'
```

You can also use the `alt` attribute as a method option and not to worry about the resource extension/format.